# Duas mascaras jquery em um campo

Tags: javascript, jquery

alguem pode me ajudar?

Tenho um input no qual ele é CPF/CNPJ, como faço uma mascara contendo dois valores diferentes para um mesmo campo? E como ficaria o codigo contendo um campo adicional de telefone? Ou seja mascara no input cpf/cnpj e mascara no telefone, so consegui do cpf, nao consigo do telefone junto!

```
<input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf">
<input type="text" name="tel" id="tel">

$(document).ready(function(){
var SPMaskBehavior = function (val) {
return val.replace(/\D/g, '').length === 11 ? '000.000.000.00' : '00.000.000/0000-01';
},
spOptions = {
onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
field.mask(SPMaskBehavior.apply({}, arguments), options);
}
};

$('#cpf').mask(SPMaskBehavior, spOptions);
});
```

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse código funciona, extrai da documentação:

```
var options =  {
  onKeyPress: function(cpf, e, field, options) { //Quando uma tecla for pressionada
    var masks = ['000.000.000-000', '00.000.000/0000-01']; //Mascaras
    var mask = (cpf.length > 14) ? masks[1] : masks[0]; //Se for de tamanho 11, usa a 2 mascara
    $('#cpf').mask(mask, options); //Sobrescreve a mascara
}};

$('#cpf').mask('000.000.000-000', options); //Aplica a mascara
```

Comment: nao funcionou, nao ta fazendo a troca da mascara quando digito mais que 11 digitos pra ir pro CNPJ, na verdade ele nem deixa eu digitar mais que 11 digitos, o que pode ser @francisco

Comment: @jean Editei a resposta, tenta agr.

Comment: agora so fica na mascara do CNPJ :( @francisco

Comment: o que pode estar errado @francisco

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/133425/

Comment: Modifiquei a resposta

Comment: perfeito @francisco, esse do cpf/cnpj funcinou certinho!
tentei adaptar o codigo agora para outra necessidade, porem nao esta dando certo como no inicio do cpf.

tenho um campo fixo/celular... o fixo segue o padrao (00) 1234-5678 ja o cel tem um digito a mais nas primeiras 5 casas decimais (00) 12345-6789 como posso adaptar o codigo, tendo em vista que tentei e nao deu certo, veja as mascaras como ficam http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/133983/

Comment: @Jean Funcionando -> http://jsfiddle.net/3o5fbk5f/2/

Comment: Muitooo obrigado @francisco pelo seu tempo dedicado!

Comment: @jean da um upvote e marca a resposta como correta pfv

Comment: oi @francisco fui implementar o codigo da mascara do cpf, entretanto vi que ele nao esta funcionando corretamente, a mascara de cpf nao esta correta, quando digita o ultimo digito do cpf ele ja muda pra mascara do cnpj, o que pode ser? https://jsfiddle.net/1bt5k8mr/

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: agora esta perfeito @francisco, mto obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o *toggleClass* e alternar as *mask*

> Segue código exemplo:|

```js
$(document).ready(function() {



  $(".cpf_cnpj").mask("999.999.999-99").attr('placeholder', '000.000.000-00');
  
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    $("#transaction_id").toggleClass('cpf_cnpj phone');
    $("#transaction_id").val('');
    $(".cpf_cnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99").attr('placeholder', '00.000.000/0000-00');
    $(".phone").mask("(999) 999-9999").attr('placeholder', '(999)999-9999');
  })



  $("#transaction_id").on("blur", function() {
    var last = $(this).val().substr($(this).val().indexOf("-") + 1);

    if (last.length == 3) {
      var move = $(this).val().substr($(this).val().indexOf("-") - 1, 1);
      var lastfour = move + last;

      var first = $(this).val().substr(0, 9);

      $(this).val(first + '-' + lastfour);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-left" id="form2" name="form2">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="input">Clique para alternar</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="toggle">Alternar</span>
        
        <input type="text" name="transaction_id" id="transaction_id" class="form-control cpf_cnpj fone" placeholder="CPF, CNPJ ou Telefone" autofocus>
        

      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda @Lollipop, mas dessa maneira compromete muito a usabilidade do formulário, tendo o usuário que executar uma ação a mais!